# UnityScript in Unity wont work correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I recently started making a new game and I'm kinda an amateur coder.

```
var FlashlightOn : boolean = true;

function Update () {
    ButtonClicket();
}

function ButtonClicket () {
    if (Input.GetButton("Flashlight")) && FlashlightOn == true {
        Destroy(Flahslight);
        FlashlightOn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Instantiate (Flashlight, Vector3(i * 0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        FlashlightOn = true;
    }
}
```

In the compiler error part it says I need to put brackets at the end and some other junk that doesn't need to be done. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Questions of this type, that deal with `Unity` and `JavaScript` really belong on Stackoverflow.  I have already flagged this question for migration.

Comment: What errors is the compiler giving?

Comment: Maybe its different in Unity and people here can correct me, but in standard javascript there's a **very** important convention that all functions are written in *camelCase* (start with a lowercase letter), unless you intend for the function to be used with the `new` keyword.

Comment: also, you should tag things with Unity. Unity javascript isn't really standard javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Having run the code through the compiler myself, the errors it's giving are valid. Your code simply has a syntax problem and a typo:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Flashlight") && FlashlightOn == true) {
```

The close parenthesis for the if statement was in the wrong place.

```
Destroy(Flashlight);
```

You misspelled 'Flashlight'.

Also, `i` isn't defined isn't this code snippet, which is fine if it's a global variable, but you may want to double check it.

Comment: Now I got 2 more errors: "Assets/GameAssets/Scripts/Flashlight.js(13,29): BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate' for the argument list '(System.Type, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Quaternion)' was found." and "Assets/GameAssets/Scripts/Flashlight.js(9,24): BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Object.Destroy' for the argument list '(System.Type)' was found." I really don't see the problem, I checked 5 times for syntax errors and for misspellings but I can't find anything.

Comment: Both of those errors are because `Flashlight` is a Type, not an Object. You can't [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) or [Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) a Type, you need an actual instance.